# Parse.com Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have some android code that tries to save data to parse. I have a parse cloud function which adds a uid field set to the user to the data in a beforeSave. When I look at the logs and data browser I notice that sometimes upto 5 entries of the data are saved. I have run the android code in a debugger and the save function is only call once.

Android code:

```
public void sendFileToParse(String name, byte[] data){
    data_file = data;
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile(name, data_file);        
    file.saveInBackground();

    //associate a ParseFile onto a ParseObject
    ParseObject post_data = new ParseObject("Files");
    post_data.put("first", 0);
    post_data.put("fileName", name);
    post_data.put("file", file);        

    post_data.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e){
            if (e == null){
                Log.d("ParseFileTransfer", "Saved file successfully");
            }
            else{
                Log.d("ParseFileTransfer", "Could not save file");
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Javascript cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Files", function(request, response) {
  var user = request.user.id;
  alert("In beforeSave");
  if (user == null){
    response.error("Users does not exist");
  }
  else{
    request.object.set("uid",user);
    request.object.save();
    response.success();
  }

});
```

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: I removed the request.object.save() from the else statement and that seems to have fixed the problem. Kind of makes sense but im not sure why the number of saves would be random.

Comment: It looks like a loop to me. Your `.beforeSave()` runs because you called the `save()` from the client. Then since you have a user, it will run the `save` again in the cloud triggering the `beforeSave()` on that object. I think the randomness but similarity of error quantity is based on how Parse is calculating the rate/limit or timeout which is some couple seconds and depending on how much strain the server is feeling at the moment.

Comment: It's definetly loop and parse beforeSave operation can only run 15 second with actual saving process.